# Going back and forward in the browser results in two "Next" buttons

Tags: bug, review

It's pretty low priority, and probably very difficult to reproduce.

Below, you can see that two next buttons have been created for this question. I navigated here using the backspace key unintentionally on a question, then by pressing forward. Silly me failed to click *inside* the edit window before editing, and it took me back here.

Neither button works.

[image: Notice the next - next]

Comment: Really weird, any idea at all how to reproduce it? I gave the code a lookthrough, but as of now I have zero clue how this might have happened.

Comment: @Emmett I have been yet unable to reproduce it, but I haven't exactly tried. I'll look into it tomorrow and get back to you!